# How did I clear the final layout accidentally

Tags: presentation, sublayout

Suddenly the Final layout was missing and it did not even fallback to the shared layout also. No body from our side did not change the layouts intentionally. How this could have happened?

Any guesses?

Note :-This happened in Master DB.

Comment: what sitecore version u r using?

Comment: Is this for a specific item or for all items?

Comment: Did you check your logs for when the item was last saved? You should enable workflow and versioning to allow you to track this and roll back if needed.

Comment: its only for one item,